# Effective way to parse list from spring to jsp array

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I am looking for effective approach to put values from spring to jsp array.

Right now, I have this working code

```
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Date', '${campaign.answer1}', '${campaign.answer2}', '${campaign.answer3}'],
      <c:forEach var="campaignsPerDay" items="${campaignsPerDay}">
      ['${campaignsPerDay.date}',  ${campaignsPerDay.votes1},  ${campaignsPerDay.votes2}, ${campaignsPerDay.votes3}],
      </c:forEach>
      ['Date', '10', '20', '30']
    ]);
```

But there is a problem, and it is the `,` at the end of this line `...{campaign.answer3}'],`

If I remove that hardcoded `['Date', '10', '20', '30']`, it is not functionable, because it looks like this :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'No', 'Neutral', 'Yes'],

          ['Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  4,  1, 2],

          ['Mon Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  3,  30, 15],

          ['Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  19,  5, 7],

        ]);
```

The `,` on the last line ruins the well-formated code. I need this :

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Date', 'No', 'Neutral', 'Yes'],

          ['Sun Apr 06 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  4,  1, 2],

          ['Mon Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  3,  30, 15],

          ['Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2014',  19,  5, 7]

        ]);
```

I am able to solve this issue, but not in "nice" or "effective" way.

What should be the best approach? I can pre-parse this in controller class if needed.

Comment: Is the format in any way JSON related?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - it is not, but I can preparse it to JSON... But I would need one more class for this. Maybe it is the best solution after all.

Comment: It might be, but it will be a weird generation since the first element in the array is a the column names.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - ah true, forgot about that :).